# What to do the following fit work using NegativeBinomial in statsmodel?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, statsmodels

I am using following code to fit on given data but algorithm could not able to convergence. I believe this is due to high frequency of zero count. I am using both NegativeBinomialP and ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP but both coult not able to converge.
It is telling "HessianInversionWarning: Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params available warnings.warn('Inverting hessian failed, no bse or cov_params.
What should I do to avoid the NaN value in the fitting coefficient?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import statsmodels.distributions.discrete as distr
from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import NegativeBinomialP, NegativeBinomial, Poisson, GeneralizedPoisson
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import (ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP, ZeroInflatedPoisson,
                                              ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson)
import statsmodels.discrete._diagnostics_count as dia

import statsmodels.api as sm


endog=[6679,469,151,52,27,12,5,5,3,6,2,1,1,2,1]
exog=[[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[1,7],[1,8],[1,9],[1,10],[1,12],[1,14],[1,25],[1,32]]


endog=np.array(endog)
exog=np.array(exog)

plt.plot(exog[:,1],endog,'r.-')
plt.xlabel('exog')
plt.ylabel('endog')
plt.savefig('plot.png')

#method 1 
#model_nb = NegativeBinomial(endog, exog, loglike_method='nb2')
#model_nb = NegativeBinomialP(endog, exog, p=2)
#res_nb = model_nb.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=5000, maxfun=5000)

#method 2 
model_zinb = ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP(endog, exog, p=2)
res_nb = model_zinb.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=5000, maxfun=5000)
print(res_nb.summary())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Err, I don't think a zero inflated model will work out very well when you have no 0's *in the endogenous* outcome you are predicting. Not sure if this is your real data, but these are perhaps too small of samples to get reliable estimates for maximum likelihood estimators (that rely on asymptotic convergence). My experience the dispersion term for negative binomial takes very large samples to estimate reliably (well north or 1k data points for the data I work with). Maybe better Poisson and correct for overdispersion is an alternative? Depends on your end goal though.

Comment: Is the data the frequency counts or individual observations? The models expect individual observations, and except for GLM, there are no case weights, `freq_weights` available. You can expand the data, e.g. add 6679 row with y=0 if this is the case, and then regress on just a constant.

Comment: endog here is the frequency counts. This data comes from single-cell transcriptomics experiment. Where negative binomial is usually fitted to find the technical and biological variabiltiy of the genes. So I was using Negative Binomial but due to sparse it looks like I have to use something else.

Comment: you can use the count models, you just need to expand the data to observations. 7000 observations is not much.